# Converter run only once during instantiation

Tags: c#, wpf, type-conversion, converters, ivalueconverter

I have this Calendar control

```
<Calendar x:Name="Calendario" SelectionMode="SingleRange" SelectedDatesChanged="Calendario_SelectedDatesChanged">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedDatesChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ProcesarFechasCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Calendario,Path=SelectedDates,Converter={l:SelectedDatesToList}}"/>    
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Calendar>
```

and this converter

```
public class SelectedDatesToList : BaseConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var selectedDates = value as IList;
        List<DateTime> ListaFechas = selectedDates.Cast<DateTime>().ToList();
        return ListaFechas;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My problem is if The converter is active my Command Allways receive value as an empty List. If I remove the converter, my command receive the List allready filled.

The converter runs only during instantiation. Even if the SelectedDates of calendar changes later the converter doesn't run anymore.

Whats wrong with my converter or my xaml ?

Comment: is your convert method being hit?

Comment: sorry but what it mean ?

Comment: i mean when you apply converter, its convert method is getting called from xaml ?

Comment: Yes it is called but only when the window starts. At least i think so. the breakpoint only stops when the window start. The command allways Works.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but I normally declare the converter as resource and use it by {StaticResource ResourceKey} extension

Comment: Tks. Allready tryed this way and nothing... Tks for your help